Своя гравитация блоку
Вот если мы в реальности подпрыгнем в летящем самолёте, ничего не случится. А если в роблоксе, то тебя отбросит назад, так как самолёт двигается, а ты нет. Как сделать так, чтобы при прыжке я, так сказать, летел дальше с самолётом? Как сделать такую привязку к самолету или же просто блоку?

Код покажите...

Нету кода, я не понимаю как такая система гравитации работает(

Уравнения покажите.

в момент отрыва от самолёта нужно присвоить объекту скорость, равную скорости самолёта
